# How to render Unreal View without inheriting Unreal Game Activity from Android

Tags: android, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, android-gameactivity

I'm going to show Unreal View only at the top of Android activity, and I'm going to show Android Native UI at the bottom.
The app is a screen with only the native UI, a screen mixed with the Unreal View, and a screen with only the Unreal View.

However, there are many screens with only the Native UI.
There is also Bottom Navigation at the bottom.
For this reason, it feels inefficient to inherit and create GameActivity.

Is there a way to meet all of the above requirements without inheriting GameActivity?
Or please give me advice on other good ways.

To render Unreal View without inheriting Unreal Game Activity from Android

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The UE platform was not designed to be anything but a top level entry point. The full-screen aspect adds to this point.

While you can add a shell around it, the reasons for doing so tend to be outweighed by the flexibility in engine.

Your custom UI can be created in engine. With proper hooks, and some custom code, the in-game UI could pass variables to the OS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I want to make tens of thousands of screens move as fast as Android Native App's list scrolls.

When creating UI through Unreal Engine, I understand that fast performance is impossible due to rendering problems. I understand that this is the same for Unity.

This is why I don't make certain UI unreal engine.

Comment: No problem, I am closing out my SO  I wish you the bleeping best.